# IN clause not working properly.

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter

I have the following query.

```
SELECT id FROM content WHERE id IN ('40,41,45')
```

Query above returns the content of `id` `40`, `41`, `45`.
Thus, the result is 3 rows will be returned.

In my case, the previous query returns one row only, the content that has id `40`.

Why does not return the rows that have these ids?

---

**Edit:**
I'm using `codeigniter` query.

```
$this->db->select('*')->where_in('id', $content)->get('content');
```

Thus, the query will be like this

```
SELECT * FROM (`content`) WHERE `id` IN ('40,41,45')
```

**How can I remove the single quotes from the query ?**

Comment: try not to quote 40, 41, 45

Comment: Is $content an array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With codeigniter your variable `$content` must be a PHP array.

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
SELECT id FROM content WHERE id IN (40,41,45);
```

Here are some examples you can look

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-in-clause.htm

Comment: Many people saw the problem with the quotes at the same time. But what is mysql doing there? It looks like it tries to convert the string to an integer, and stops at the first error without reporting it. Postgresql does not accept this syntax.

Comment: Thanks, but please look at my question again, there is an addition.

Comment: Dont know much about codeignitor but found here http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html its written u need to send it as array

Answer (score 0):

Your wrapped single quotes makes this problem.

Try

```
SELECT id FROM content WHERE id IN ('40,41,45')
```

Comment: Just give every answer that helps somehow a click up, then green checkmark is for the selected solution... oops, that goes @LionKing